# Multithreaded OpenGL Rendering Pipeline

Tags: c++, c++11, multithreading, windows, opengl

I've decided to move my rendering code to a separate thread, to help facilitate the move I've created a pipeline system for rendering. With this pipeline I can insert commands into a queue which will be processed later on the rendering thread. Thus far the code has proven to work well, but I would like to know if there is anything I can do better.

There are a few things I would like to know:

1. Does the code have a reasonably fast locking system, if not is there any way I can improve it?
2. Am I properly locking around data accesses, and should I be using more mutexes?
3. When I pass parameters for the queue I use a structure than can store 8 parameters (8 64 bit integers) - I only store the data needed for the command in the buffer - is there any way with templates (potentially varargs) that I can make the parameter passing cleaner?

I've removed a significant number of commands (rendering functions) for brevity.

The `RenderingPipeline` class header:

```
#pragma once

#include <cstdint>
#include <thread>
#include <mutex>
#include <Windows.h>

// The various rending instructions.
// Some have been removed for brevity.
enum class RenderingOpcode : std::uint8_t
{
    FINISH_RENDER = 1, // First opcode set to 1 instead of 0 to allow for faster thread locking.
    LOAD_SHADER_UNIFORM,
    ACTIVATE_SHADER_PROGRAM,
    GL_DRAW_ARRAYS,
    GL_CLEAR_BUFFERS
};

// The various uniform types.
// Some have been removed for brevity.
enum class ShaderUniformType : std::uint8_t
{
    INTEGER,
    FLOAT,
    MAT4F
};

// Some simple macros to make parameter packing easier
#define PACK_FLOAT(__F)  (reinterpret_cast<std::uint32_t&>(__F))
#define PACK_DOUBLE(__D) (reinterpret_cast<std::uint64_t&>(__F))
#define PACK_PTR(__P)    (reinterpret_cast<std::uint64_t>(__P))

/**
 *  A series of parameters for an instruction.
 *
 *  Ideally I would use templates, potentially with varargs.
 */
struct ParameterPack final
{
    std::uint64_t p0, p1, p2, p3, p4, p5, p6, p7;

    ParameterPack(std::uint64_t _p0 = 0, std::uint64_t _p1 = 0, std::uint64_t _p2 = 0, std::uint64_t _p3 = 0, 
                  std::uint64_t _p4 = 0, std::uint64_t _p5 = 0, std::uint64_t _p6 = 0, std::uint64_t _p7 = 0)
        : p0(_p0), p1(_p1), p2(_p2), p3(_p3), p4(_p4), p5(_p5), p6(_p6), p7(_p7)
    { }

    ~ParameterPack() = default;

    ParameterPack(const ParameterPack&) = default;
    ParameterPack(ParameterPack&&) = default;

    ParameterPack& operator =(const ParameterPack&) = default;
    ParameterPack& operator =(ParameterPack&&) = default;
};

class RenderingPipeline final
{
private:
    std::uint8_t* _instBuffer;
    std::uint32_t _insertPtr;
    std::uint32_t _instPtr;

    volatile bool _initialReady;
    volatile bool _readyForInsert;
    volatile bool _running;
    std::mutex    _mutex;
    std::thread   _renderThread;
public:
    RenderingPipeline(HDC hdc, HGLRC renderingContext, const std::uint32_t bufferSize = 16384);

    ~RenderingPipeline();

    void pushInstruction(const RenderingOpcode opcode, const ParameterPack&& params);
private:
    void runRenderingCycle();

    void renderThreadFunc(HDC hdc, HGLRC renderingContext);
};
```

The `RenderingPipeline` class implementation:

```
#include <cstring>
#include <GL/glew.h>

#include "RenderingPipeline.hpp"

RenderingPipeline::RenderingPipeline(HDC hdc, HGLRC renderingContext, const std::uint32_t bufferSize)
    : _instBuffer(new std::uint8_t[bufferSize]), _insertPtr(0), _instPtr(0),
      _initialReady(false), _readyForInsert(true), _running(true), _renderThread(&RenderingPipeline::renderThreadFunc, this, window)
{
    _mutex.lock();
    /* Unload context on main thread. 
       The context will be loaded on the rendering thread.
       Not entirely sure if this required. 
     */
    wglMakeCurrent(nullptr, nullptr);
    std::memset(_instBuffer, 0, bufferSize);
    _initialReady = true; // Notify the rendering thread that the buffer is cleared.
    _mutex.unlock();
}

RenderingPipeline::~RenderingPipeline()
{ 
    _mutex.lock();
    _running = false;
    _mutex.unlock();
    _renderThread.join();
    delete[] _instBuffer; 
}

void RenderingPipeline::pushInstruction(const RenderingOpcode opcode, const ParameterPack&& params)
{
    /*
     *    After the `RenderingOpcode::FINISH_RENDER` insruction
     *  is inserted we lock insertion until the rendering thread
     *  loops through everything.
     *
     *  This will yield the main thread until the rendering thread finishes.
     */
    do
    {
        _mutex.lock();
        if(_readyForInsert)
        {
            _mutex.unlock();
            break;
        }
        _mutex.unlock();
        std::this_thread::yield();
    } while(true);

    _mutex.lock();
    _instBuffer[_insertPtr++] = static_cast<std::uint8_t>(opcode);

// Macro to copy data into the instruction buffer.
#define LOAD_VALUE(__VAR) std::memcpy(reinterpret_cast<void*>(_instBuffer + _insertPtr), reinterpret_cast<const void*>(&__VAR), sizeof(__VAR)); \
                          _insertPtr += sizeof(__VAR);

    switch(opcode)
    {
        case RenderingOpcode::FINISH_RENDER: 
        {
            _readyForInsert = false;
            break;
        }
        case RenderingOpcode::LOAD_SHADER_UNIFORM: 
        {
            const ShaderUniformType uniformType = static_cast<ShaderUniformType>(params.p0);
            const std::int32_t uniformID = static_cast<std::int32_t>(params.p1);

            _instBuffer[_insertPtr++] = static_cast<std::uint8_t>(uniformType);
            LOAD_VALUE(uniformID);

            switch(uniformType)
            {
                case ShaderUniformType::INTEGER:
                {
                    LOAD_VALUE(params.p2);
                    break;
                }
                case ShaderUniformType::FLOAT:
                {
                    const std::uint32_t iVal = static_cast<std::uint32_t>(params.p2);
                    const float fVal = reinterpret_cast<const float&>(iVal);
                    LOAD_VALUE(fVal);
                    break;
                }
                case ShaderUniformType::MAT4F:
                {
                    const float* const mat = reinterpret_cast<const float*>(params.p2);
                    LOAD_VALUE(mat);
                    break; 
                }
                default: break;
            }
            break; 
        }
        case RenderingOpcode::GL_DRAW_ARRAYS:
        {
            const GLenum  drawArraysMode  = static_cast<GLenum>(params.p0);
            const GLint   drawArraysFirst = static_cast<GLint>(params.p1);
            const GLsizei drawArraysCount = static_cast<GLsizei>(params.p2);

            LOAD_VALUE(drawArraysMode);
            LOAD_VALUE(drawArraysFirst);
            LOAD_VALUE(drawArraysCount);
            break;
        }
        case RenderingOpcode::GL_CLEAR_BUFFERS:
        {
            const GLbitfield clearBuffers = static_cast<GLbitfield>(params.p0);
            LOAD_VALUE(clearBuffers);
            break;
        }
        default: break;
    }

#undef LOAD_VALUE

    _mutex.unlock();
}

void RenderingPipeline::runRenderingCycle()
{
// Macro to retrieve values from the instruction buffer.
#define GET_VALUE(__TYPE, __VAR) const __TYPE __VAR = *reinterpret_cast<const __TYPE*>(_instBuffer + _instPtr); \
                                 _instPtr += sizeof(__VAR);
    _instPtr = 0;

    while(true)
    {
        std::uint8_t instByte;

        /*
         *  If there is no instruction ready yield the thread.
         *
         *  This is why the first `RenderingOpcode` has a value of 1 instead of 0.
         */
        while(true)
        {
            _mutex.lock();
            instByte = _instBuffer[_instPtr];
            _mutex.unlock();
            if(instByte != 0) { break; }
            std::this_thread::yield();
        }
        ++_instPtr;

        const RenderingOpcode currOpcode = static_cast<RenderingOpcode>(instByte);

        if(currOpcode == RenderingOpcode::FINISH_RENDER) { break; }

        switch(currOpcode)
        {
            case RenderingOpcode::LOAD_SHADER_UNIFORM:
            {
                GET_VALUE(ShaderUniformType, uniformType);
                GET_VALUE(std::int32_t, uniformID);

                switch(uniformType)
                {
                    case ShaderUniformType::INTEGER:
                    {
                        GET_VALUE(std::uint64_t, iVal);
                        glUniform1i(uniformID, static_cast<GLint>(iVal));
                        break;
                    }
                    case ShaderUniformType::FLOAT:
                    {
                        GET_VALUE(float, fVal);
                        glUniform1f(uniformID, fVal);
                        break;
                    }
                    case ShaderUniformType::MAT4F:
                    {
                        GET_VALUE(float*, mat);
                        glUniformMatrix4fv(uniformID, 1, GL_FALSE, mat);
                        break;
                    }
                    default: break;
                }
                break;
            }
            case RenderingOpcode::ACTIVATE_SHADER_PROGRAM:
            {
                GET_VALUE(GLuint, shaderProgramID);
                glUseProgram(shaderProgramID);
                break;
            }
            case RenderingOpcode::GL_DRAW_ARRAYS:
            {
                GET_VALUE(GLenum, drawArraysMode);
                GET_VALUE(GLint, drawArraysFirst);
                GET_VALUE(GLsizei, drawArraysCount);

                glDrawArrays(drawArraysMode, drawArraysFirst, drawArraysCount);
                break;
            }
            case RenderingOpcode::GL_CLEAR_BUFFERS:
            {
                GET_VALUE(GLbitfield, clearBuffers);
                glClear(clearBuffers);
                break;
            }
            default: break;
        }
    }

    _mutex.lock();
    std::memset(_instBuffer, 0, _instPtr);
    _insertPtr = 0;
    _readyForInsert = true;
    _mutex.unlock();
#undef GET_VALUE
}

void RenderingPipeline::renderThreadFunc(HDC hdc, HGLRC renderingContext)
{
    // Wait for instruction buffer to be cleared.
    do
    {
        _mutex.lock();
        if(_initialReady)
        {
            _mutex.unlock();
            break;
        }
        _mutex.unlock();
        std::this_thread::yield();
    } while(true);

    // Re-assign OpenGL rendering context to this rendering thread.
    wglMakeCurrent(hdc, renderingContext);

    // Some basic OpenGL setup.
    glEnable(GL_DEPTH_TEST);
    glEnable(GL_CULL_FACE);
    glCullFace(GL_BACK);
    glFrontFace(GL_CW);

    while(true)
    {
        _mutex.lock();
        if(!_running) 
        {
            _mutex.unlock();
            break; 
        }
        _mutex.unlock();

        runRenderingCycle();
        SwapBuffers(hdc);
    }
}
```

An example of how it supposed to be used:

```
void exampleUsage(HDC hdc, HGLRC renderingContex, GLuint shaderProgram)
{
    RenderingPipeline rp(hdc, renderingContex);

    while(true)
    {
        rp.pushInstruction(RenderingOpcode::ACTIVATE_SHADER_PROGRAM, ParameterPack(shaderProgram));
        // ...
        rp.pushInstruction(RenderingOpcode::FINISH_RENDER, ParameterPack());
    }
}
```